# Google Sheets / Excel - If, IsError, Match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets

In Google Sheets I have a sheet with two data sets:  NumberedPrime(the number prime, ie: 11th Prime to 10,000) and PrimeValues (the actual prime numbers, ie: 2,3,5,7,11,etc).

I have an entry field in B6, that will allow me to key a value I want. In C6,  want it to let me know that if it's prime, which numbered prime it is, or just say "NOT PRIME".  I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing or got backwards from my equation in C6.

Cell C6:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B6,PrimeValues,NumberedPrime))=FALSE,NumberedPrime,"NOT PRIME")
```

Currently, if I enter say, 58 in B6, C6 says the value is 5, when obviously that number is not prime.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Apologies in advance if this is not detailed enough.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B6,'Prime Numbers'!B2:C10001,2,0),"NOT PRIME")
```